# Why text annotation labels are not the same size as other text on the plot even though the size was set to be the same?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAs5w.png)All the text size for text labels above lines is 10 and it's also 10 for my axis labels yet they don't look the same size once on the plot.

```
  geom_line(lwd = 1) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue1","green4", "orchid2", "orangered"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 6, 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, -0.004, -0.0006))+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = -1.885727e-03, label = "*", vjust = -0.5, size = 10, family = "sans", fontface = "plain")+
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = -3.355709e-03, label = "*", vjust = -0.5, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = -3.e-03, label = "*", vjust = -0.52, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 0, label = "a", size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = -2.237154e-03, label = "*", vjust = -0.5, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 5, y = -3.177662e-03, label = "a", vjust = -2.25, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 5, y = -8.320587e-04, label = "b", vjust = -1, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 5, y = -1.314674e-03, label = "ab", hjust = 1.2, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 5, y = -1.251930e-03, label = "b", vjust = -0.3, hjust = -0.4, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = -3.010294e-03, label = "a", vjust = -1, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = -1.298422e-03, label = "ab", vjust = 2.5, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = -1.025298e-03, label = "b", hjust = -0.1, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = -7.609683e-04, label = "b", vjust = -0.75, size = 10, family = "sans")+
  annotate("text", x = 6, y = -0.004, label = "A", size = 10, family = "sans")+
  #Remove panel borders and grid lines
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans", color = "black", size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = ("none"),
        text=element_text(size=10))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Respiration-se, ymax=Respiration+se), width=.5,
                position=position_dodge(0.00))
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVvg.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Text in theme elements are specified in points, as per the [`element_text()` documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html#arguments). Text in geoms/stats/annotation/layers are specified in millimeters, as per the [vignette](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#font-size). You can convert the text in layers to points by setting e.g. `size = 10 / .pt`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = "I'm an axis label at 8 millimeters",
  y = "I'm an axis label at 8 points",
  lab = c("I'm layer text at 8 points", "I'm layer text at 8 millimeters")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = lab)) +
  geom_text(
    size = c(8 / .pt, 8),
    vjust = c(1, -1)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8 * .pt),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>